# GEOSERVER Admin logging issue on docker installation

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, geoserver

I'm having a invalid Username/Password message with the defaut admin/geoserver combo.

My setup:
A baremetal unbuntu 22.04 running docker.
A container docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24.2 with port redirection 33631:8080
I've redirected the DNS  geoserver.my_site.com  A baremetal_IP

And a nginx reverse proxy

server {
server_name geoserver.my_site.com;

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:33631;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/geoserver.my_site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/geoserver.my_site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
```

}

I can access to the geoserver via https but when i try to log in with the defaut admin/geoserver combo:
1- firefox tell me that i'll send unencrypted data
2- i say ok
3- i get an error message with incorrect username / password

I've passed a few hours without any clue.

I've tried to change the docker env var :
SSL, GEOSERVER_ADMIN_PASSWORD, CORS_ENABLED nothing works still the same message

Thx for your help or any advice

Comment: Did you set the proxy URL in GeoServer?